# Can installing Ubuntu on my PC/mac destroy it or harm it in any way? And will I still have my previous data (files, images, etc...)?

Tags: system-installation

If I install Ubuntu on my mac or PC will it harm it or delete any files?

After installing Ubuntu will I still have my old files and pictures and stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install Ubuntu (vs. trying it from a Live USB/CD) you will need to create space on your Hard drive for a set of Ubuntu only partition(s). This is where Ubuntu system files, and potentially user data will be housed.

Option 1:
You can chose to use your entire drive for Ubuntu, you will have to format it and hence by extension will be voluntarily deleting all your data from it.

Option 2:
Keep your original OS (OS X or Windows) as is, and instead create a new partition of at the very least 20GB in the free space of your hard drive (assuming you only have one drive). Then install Ubuntu in that newly created partition. In this approach your original data will remain untouched.

Comment: will I still be able to boot back to windows?

Comment: in Option 2 you will be able to boot back into Windows. Ubuntu installs a boot manager called GRUB, which will allow you to boot into either OS (Ubuntu or Windows) upon startup.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you do it. If you do it the right way it won't destroy any data, and all files will remain.

First of all you need some free/unallocated space on your HDD where you can put the Linux partition. If your disk has an MBR partition table you can only have 4 primary partitions. You can have more than 4 partition if you create an extended partition then you will be able to create a few more logical partitions inside this extended partition.

I suggest having more than 16Gb of free space for your Ubuntu, depending on how you are going to use it.

To get this unallocated space you have to shrink one of the partition/s from your HDD. If you are a Windows user here you can read about how to do it: [Easily Shrink a Volume on a Windows 7 Disk](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309169.aspx)

**The steps from the link:**

> 1. Open the Disk Management console by typing diskmgmt.msc at an elevated command prompt.
> 2. In Disk Management, right-click the volume that you want to shrink, and then click **Shrink Volume**.
> 3. In the field provided in the Shrink dialog box, enter the amount of space by which to shrink the disk.
> 4. Click **Shrink**.

In some cases windows wont let you shrink the partition enough, you can look about here [How to shrink Windows 7 boot partition with unmovable files](https://superuser.com/questions/88131/how-to-shrink-windows-7-boot-partition-with-unmovable-files)

When you have your free space you can then start with the Ubuntu installation. Read carefully the steps related to partitioning. You should be able to see the unallocated space on your HDD. This unallocated space is where the Ubuntu partitions should go.

At the end of the installation you should have a dual boot.